# What's wrong with this method?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java can someone please explain to me what's wrong with this method:

```
clas Hello {
public static void main (String[]arg) {
Document.write ("hello world") ; 
}}
```

Comment: ehm ... self explainatory -.-

Comment: Be sure you are not confusing **Java** and **Javascript**. They are different languages, despite the similarity in name.

Comment: java:javascript :: car:carpet

Answer (score 14):

This is the compiler output:

```
Hello.java:1: 'class' or 'interface' expected
clas Hello {
^
1 error
```

That means, that you should either type `class` or `interface` ( In your case it should be **class** )

Assuming you had an error while copy/pasting it here, the problem reported by the compiler is:

```
Hello.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Document
location: class Hello
        Document.write ("hello world") ; 
        ^
1 error
```

That means, the compiler doesn't know anything about a class named: `Document`  that's what *cannot find symbol*  means in this case.

Perhaps you want to write:

```
 System.out.println("Hello world");
```

Complete running program:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for teaching him how to understand the compiler errors, so he can learn how to solve the problems himself

Comment: Thank you both. I'm teaching my self Python and sometimes error messages that look "too obvious" for a mid-level programmer in a language are completely awkward for somebody new to the lang. Having this in mind I hope my answer help to understand better the problem to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You probably meant this:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvoting with a reason is helpful to everyone. Downvoting without one is just not.

Answer (score 3):

1. You misspelled `class`.
2. Where is `Document` coming from?
3. The formatting is terrible.

Comment: I think they might be getting confused with JavaScript's `document.write`.